# Django: Add JS to Form at runtime

Tags: javascript, django, runtime

I tried this:

```
my_form.media.add_js(['path-to/foo.js'])
```

But `foo.js` was never added.

I found out that `media` is a property. This way it gets created each time I use `my_form.media`. As a result `add_js()` does only add to a temporary media object, which will be gone in the next Python line.

How to add JS files to a django form at runtime?

Comment: (I may have misunderstood your question) Once django serves the page, it is no longer in control of it. The client browser now holds the page it is viewing and all js files linked to it. You can make a AJAX request for JS files, and load them on the fly, or supply a list of js files that will be requested at runtime. In both cases, you will have to insert code for retrieving the JS and initialising in your page.

Comment: @kicker86 Yes, you have misunderstood me. The response has not left the server up to now. I have a form instance and want to add a JS file to its media at runtime. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Please take a look at the Media class here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/media/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to include JS (or CSS) in your forms. Use **one** of them, **not both**.

**1. Using `class Media`**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # form fields ...
    
    class Media:
        js = ('file_name.js', )
```

**2. Using `media` property**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # fields ...
    
    @property
    def media(self):
        media = super(MyForm, self).media
        
        js = ('file_name.js',)
        
        media.add_js(js)
        return media
```

Comment: I was not aware that you can create a property called `media`. This answer solves my question. Thank you. Now I found the relevant docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/media/#dynamic-property